# Using SP's document rendering engine in a 3rd party utility

Tags: spservices

New to the community. Wondering if it's possible to call SP's document rendering engine from a third party utility.

What I'd like to do is call it from my application, so that I can take a MS Word Document or a PDF or whatever, and then use the HTML/CSS that SharePoint creates to display the document nicely.

Seems like something that might be possible, but I don't know a lot about SharePoint. Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "...SP's document rendering engine..." you mean [Office Web Apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431685%28v=office.14%29.aspx) then I think the short answer is no, there is no direct/supported API:

[How can i extend Office Web Apps?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/webapps-word/how-can-i-extend-office-web-apps/9832a4a0-5b22-48bb-9d39-9e120cd0f26a).

However, in theory I don't see why you couldn't use an `iframe` to embed the "edit in browser" experience into a custom application (assuming the URL was correct). SharePoint's OOTB Page Viewer web part is often [used for this purpose](http://weblogs.asp.net/mnissen/archive/2010/09/09/display-a-powerpoint-deck-in-sharepoint-2010-using-office-web-apps.aspx).